# Google Appscript deployment quota

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, chatbot

Is there a limit to the number of deployments of appscript project? I was wondering cause I can still deploy my other projects but we can't deploy our most active one? It keeps on loading. It's like this for about 5 minutes now

Comment: Can you provide more details about your situation? Are you trying to deploy as web app? Is the user trying to deploy it the same as the script owner? Finally, can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: we're trying to deploy it as add-on. it's okay now. we just had too many deployed versions we had to delete some of them

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Actually Google have deployment limit as 200. If you try in new editor after 200 deployments it will keep on loading.
So, You have to go to old classic editor -> Publish tab -> Deploy from manifest -> Delete some old versions -> Go to new editor -> Try new or manage deploy, it will work.